# How to get Terminal in trusty to show screen dimensions while being resized as per precise

Tags: gnome-terminal

In Precise, when you clicked and held left mouse button down while on the windows edge, it would pop up a little box in the centre of the Terminal window showing the current screen dimensions as Columns x Rows. As you resized the Terminal screen, it would show you the new size so you could easily get the exact screen dimensions you need.

This is very useful if you are running an older character based app which needs specific screen dimensions.

I know you can change the screen size in the profile preferences and when you open a new Terminal window in the default profile, it will open to the defined screen size, but if you often change screen sizes, it is a pain to have to open a new Terminal window to get back to the dimensions you need.

The little box showing Columns x Rows is not appearing at all in my new trusty VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install CompizConfig Settings Manager.

The extra plugins (`sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins-extra`) has a "[resize window](http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Resize)" plugin under "Utility". Choose the option to "Show resize info for all windows"  and all windows will show the dimensions.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Although I don't seem to need it, Where is the "Show Resize Info for all Windows" option?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see Resize Info in the Utility section, install Plugin Extras.

sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins-extra